# Mobile website only displaying on 30% of the screen with widths set to 100% and meta viewport set to device-width

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta-tags

I am building a website (www.krausshaus.publishpath.com/khweb-websites-burritocove) and am having difficulty with my viewport.  I have 100% widths set and have set the viewport with `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, but on a mobile phone (iphone 4 and 6 safari and chrome so far), my divs with 100% widths only take up about 30% of the width of my screen.

Why does this happen?  Shouldn't 100% mean 100% when the viewport is set to device width?

The problem, as it turns out, was an image wrapped in a section that extended beyond the margins of my site.  Why that did not constrain itself to the 70% width I gave it, I cannot say.

Comment: Could we have either some code for context, or even a link to your site? There is a possibility you didn't close you're media query correctly. You may have a parent container not set to `100%`, it's hard to tell with no context.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: @ether thank you for responding.  While I do have the url to the site in question in my question, the problem is only on mobile devices and I have actually identified the problem and apologize for wasting everyone's time with my obvious naivety in utilizing this forum for the first time.

Comment: @BSMP I made a judgement call on not including the code (which was obviously the wrong call) because the problem is only on mobile and I didn't think anyone would be able to do anything with the code I would have posted here.  Once again, obviously I was wrong and I will try to do a better job next time I post a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

An element with width:100% actually inherits the explicit width of its parent or containing element. And then it is still subject to padding and margins. So look first at your parent elements and any other interfering styles.

You could also try width:100vw; (viewport width).

But looking at your website, you do indeed have your .selectionMobile class set to width:100%, but your .description class is set to width:0px, and left:50%. Eliminate those two style definitions and suddenly your page looks much better.

Comment: Answers are reserved for "answers." You shouldn't suggest a user does something through the answer feature, that is what the comments are for.

Comment: @ether Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @ericgilchrist thank you for visiting my site, checking out my code and attempting to help.  While this didn't fix my problem, I do appreciate the help.  The code portion to which you referred is that way for a reason, but it currently isn't doing what I meant it to do (but it will).